# Macro copies certains column from one sheet to other. Fine can't get it to paste from row 4 on sheet 2 instead of row 2

Tags: excel, vba

Macro copies certain columns from one sheet to other. I can't get it to paste from row 4 on sheet 2 instead of row 2.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Long, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 4) = sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Skip the loop: `Sheet2.Cells(erow, 2).Resize(lastrow-1).Value = sheet1.cells(2,3).resize(lastrow-1).Value`

Comment: I do not get it. Not working.

Comment: Works fine thank you!

Answer (score 1):

skip the loop and assign the whole range as one:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim erow As Long
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value = sheet1.Cells(2, 3).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 3).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value = sheet1.Cells(2, 4).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 4).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value = sheet1.Cells(2, 9).Resize(lastrow - 1).Value
End Sub
```